# pandas, pytz - simple timezone convert

Tags: python, pandas, pytz

I have the following dict:

`{'actual': {Timestamp('2013-02-20 13:30:00'): 0.93000000000000005}}`

I change it to a df:

```
df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='columns', dtype=None)
```

if I perform:

```
df.index = df.index.tz_localize('US/Eastern').tz_convert(pytz.utc)
```

The df timestamp is correctly converted and returns:

```
                           actual
2013-02-20 18:30:00+00:00    0.93
```

However if I split the command in 2 lines such as :

```
df.index= df.index.tz_localize('US/Eastern')
df.index.tz_convert(pytz.utc)
```

it does not gets converted and returns:

```
                           actual
2013-02-20 13:30:00-05:00    0.93
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit: Hi, yes, will add it to the tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to assign the index back to `df` in the second line:

```
import pytz
df.index = df.index.tz_localize('US/Eastern')
df.index = df.index.tz_convert(pytz.utc)

df
#                         actual
#2013-02-20 18:30:00+00:00  0.93
```

Comment: Hmm ok - I am quite new to Pandas, but I would say that this is not the standard behavior for attribute modifictaion is it?

Comment: This is actually a quite standard way to modify attribute. Since in pandas, most of the functions are functional, i.e. they don't modify object in place unless explicitly told to do so.

Comment: Ok i understand now. Thx, was very useful.